# How to keep image the same size (and crop the excess) inside a flexible div?

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a flexible div and I want the image to stay the same size no matter if the div is being resized, the image should just be hidden (centering it would also be a great add-on). How to achieve this?

Below is my current code, this causes the image to shrink when the div is being resized. Thank you!

```css
.banner-img {
  max-width: 30%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.banner-img img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x100" alt="" /></div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking **as the code you have provided does not demonstrate the issue.**

Comment: You want your `banner-img` to have a particular height?

Comment: OK, i think I got it.
I have a max-width:100% rule in my css which is getting in the way, so applying also a max-width:250px to the image solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Flex is a good solution to center your image

```css
.banner-img {
  max-width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.banner-img img {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x100" alt="" /></div>
```

Comment: If you feel this solved the problem, please mark the answer as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In `.banner-img img`, you can add `object-fit: cover` and change the `width: 250px` from pixels to percentage, like this:

```css
.banner-img {
    max-width:30%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.banner-img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x100" alt="" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this with making an [image as background](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp) and align the background position to center:

```css
.banner-img {
  width: 250px;
  max-width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/250x100") center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-img"></div>
```